# Get drop-down list values from Yahoo Finance

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get the values from a drop-down list found on a Yahoo finance page.  Here is the link to the page: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/options?p=AAPL

I would like to get the values from this drop-down list.  For example: 1536278400,1536883200, etc, and put them in an array.

```
<select class="Fz(s)" data-reactid="5">
<option selected="" value="1536278400" data-reactid="6">September 7, 2018</option>
<option value="1536883200" data-reactid="7">September 14, 2018</option>
<option value="1537488000" data-reactid="8">September 21, 2018</option>
<option value="1538092800" data-reactid="9">September 28, 2018</option>
<option value="1538697600" data-reactid="10">October 5, 2018</option>
<option value="1539302400" data-reactid="11">October 12, 2018</option>
<option value="1539907200" data-reactid="12">October 19, 2018</option>
<option value="1542326400" data-reactid="13">November 16, 2018</option>
<option value="1545350400" data-reactid="14">December 21, 2018</option>
<option value="1547769600" data-reactid="15">January 18, 2019</option>
<option value="1550188800" data-reactid="16">February 15, 2019</option>
<option value="1555545600" data-reactid="17">April 18, 2019</option>
<option value="1561075200" data-reactid="18">June 21, 2019</option>
<option value="1579219200" data-reactid="19">January 17, 2020</option>
<option value="1592524800" data-reactid="20">June 19, 2020</option>
</select>
```

Viewing the log from the following code shows that not all of the source code is there and the code for the drop-down list is completely missing.

```
function getData() {
  var url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/options?p=AAPL"; 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

I assume this has something to do with the page being loaded dynamically, but I've disabled JavaScript within the developer tool in Chrome and the page still loads with all the content.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try a regex match here or try convert the text into html and select the elements

Comment: Use a regEx something like this.. `value="(.*)" `

Comment: Use an API to get data programmatically. Much more reliable than webpage scraping, especially since many pages load content dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  Unfortunately, regex won't work because the code for the drop-down list isn't in the response from UrlFetchApp.  Yes, an API would be much better and I did end up finding one, but I still would like to know if there are any solutions for problems like this using GAS.